# Exact representation of location in a legal text as string

Tags: database, database-design, format, standards, iso

Given a legal text as the EU-[General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) one wants to have reference to an exact location in that or another law.

In common written language one would write something like

`Art. 13(1c) GDPR` or
`Section 41(1)(2), first sentence MyLaw`.

**How represent such text as a short string for storing in databases or querying results in a deterministic and exact way?**

One could think of something such as `GDPR-13-1-c` or `MyLaw-42-1-2-S1`.

I am also comparing to ISO country or language codes such as ES for Spain or en-EN for the English language.

Comment: Don't use a string. Put each piece of information in a separate table column instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's always important to separate the concerns of data *storage* with data *rendering*.

Text such as `Art. 13(1c) GDPR or Section 41(1)(2), first sentence MyLaw.` is a *rendering* of multiple pieces of data. If you don't care about any of the pieces individually, then it could make sense to treat it as single value and store it in a single column.

However, you have raised checking the country code etc, so it's clear you do care about at least some of the individual pieces, so store them separately in separate columns.

This would enable you for example to have a country code table and create a foreign key constraint from that part of the data to the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up from a data management perspective. However, I am rather looking into a standard format (schema?) of law contents. Clearly, I could think of such a schema on my own, but I would rather use something more established for portability or interoperability reasons.